# can't send mail in php using external smtp server

Tags: php, windows, smtp

I'm trying to send mail out from an external smtp server using a php script below,

```
<?php
$recipient="john_doe@gmail.com"; 
$subject="Website to customer";
$message="Customer Name: ".$_POST['name']."\r\n";
$message.="Customer Email: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n";
$message.="Customer Message: ".$_POST['msg']."\r\n"; 
$mailheader="From: <maria@comcast.net> \r\n";
$mailheader.="Reply to ".$_POST['email'];
ini_set("SMTP","comcast.net");
mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $mailheader);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sending mail from website to Customer</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Thanks, <strong><?php echo $_POST['name']; ?></strong>, for your message.</p>
<p>Your email address: <strong><?php echo $_POST['email']; ?></strong></p>
<p>Your message: <br/><?php echo $_POST['msg']; ?></p>
</body>
<html>
```

I got an error message:

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "comcast.net" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\sendmail.php on line 10
```

Is that because I don't have a local email server?  Will phpmailer solve my problem?  Can anyone guide me to the right direction please?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: The error could be literal. It could be that comcast is blocking outgoing port 25 connections for spam reasons. They might have a different port you can use like 2525.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mail() \[function.mail\]: Failed to connect to mailserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011300/warning-mail-function-mail-failed-to-connect-to-mailserver)

Comment: Not the same as the possible duplicate since it's not localhost here.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. 5 seconds on google found this, http://customer.comcast.com/help-and-support/internet/list-of-blocked-ports/

use port 465. You may need to setup account information to send outgoing on their servers too.

Comment: I changed the port to 465 in php.ini and restarted Apache.  Funny thing is I got the same error message as if I was stilling using port 25.  Did I miss anything?  What do you mean "setup account information to send outgoing on their servers"?  Thanks.  Maria.

Comment: See @Andrzej's answer, it has more correct details.  Search around this site (bunch in the related questions sidebar) for sending using SMTP + google mail for the php packages you'll need. Then just use the comcast server & port.

Answer (score 1):

Use `smtp.comcast.net` instead of `comcast.net` as `SMTP` parameter. Set `smtp_port` parameter to `587`.
**BUT** Page [2] suggests that you will need SMTP AUTHentication not suported by php-mail. See page [3] for available alternatives.

**URL(s):**
1. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php
2. http://customer.comcast.com/help-and-support/internet/email-client-programs-with-xfinity-email/
3. [php.ini & SMTP= - how do you pass username & password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112190/php-ini-smtp-how-do-you-pass-username-password)

Comment: I've tried port 465 and 587. But I still got the same error message as if I was stilling using port 25. I restarted Apache, restarted my computer, but it keeps saying "Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "comcast.net" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\sendmail.php on line 10".  This is so frustrating.

Comment: Do you get SMTP greeting when you you telnet the ports? `telnet smtp.comcast.net 587`

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Telnet in Windows.  When I typed in "telnet smtp.comcast.net 587", it says invalid command.  What should be the right command?  Thanks, Andrzej.

Comment: The telnet message is "220 omta11.westchester.pa.mail.comcast.net comcast ESMTP server ready                                        Connection to host lost."  I guess that means there is no connection.  What can I do now?