# Failed to connect to mailserver

Tags: php

I have an error while sending e-mail through a php script. Although I changed all the required settings in `php.ini` like

```
SMTP            "localhost"     PHP_INI_ALL      
smtp_port       "25"           PHP_INI_ALL  
sendmail_from   NULL           PHP_INI_ALL   
sendmail_path   NULL           PHP_INI_SYSTEM
```

I am using `wamp`. The received error is this:

> [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "PHP_INI_ALL" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\mail.php on line 10

Why does this error occur ?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what SMTP server you've installed, so I guess you don't have any.

Answer (score 2):

Wampp doesn't come with a default mail server. You have to install one yourself.

If you only need a mailserver for development purposes you can download the 'smtp4dev' from here: http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/

From an answer on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7011373/1379394)

> t's a beautiful little piece of software that sits in your task bar
>   and lets you see all email that is being sent to it. It doesn't
>   actually send email anywhere, so you can work with live data without
>   fear of spamming someone.
>
> Then, when you want your application to actually send email (when you
>   run it on the server), you will need an SMTP server address instead of
>   "localhost". If you don't know which SMTP to use, speak to your
>   network administrator or ISP.

Hope that will help you.

Comment: XAMPP does come with a mail server `Mercury`

Comment: Ah I read somewhere that it didn't come with a mailserver, But I'm not using it anymore since 2010 or so. Thanks for your respond :)

Comment: Well it's not ready. You have to configure it along with php.

Answer (score 2):

WAMP runs on Windows, and windows does not have a Mail Server installed by default.

I would suggest hMailer as I use it myself, but it is not exactly childs play to setup.

Alternatively you could use phpMailer which is a php based utility that will help you send mail using for example a yahoo/gmail etc account.